# wo url serving default.aspx

Tags: routing

i've setup various rewrite rules within sitecore using the url rewrite module.
for some really bizarre reason `/wo` refuses to work, and browsing to `/wo` on other Sitecore sites I've worked on appears to load the `default.aspx` page.

`/woo` or `/w[a-z]` other than `/wo` correctly serves up a 404.

How is Sitecore resolving `/wo` to the `default.aspx` page and is there a way of disabling this route so that a 404 is returned, which will get my rewrite rule working?

If `/wo` returns a 404 on your site, this would confuse me more, but can someone please confirm/deny the behaviour in the comments? Just one person will do. then we can hopefully focus on why `/wo` is behaving like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Sitecore (the .net framework underneath actually) is detecting your "wo" as a language (Wolof - Senegal).

There is a setting in Sitecore called `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage`. If you would set that to false (patch it) I think your "wo" will also give the 404.